# Meteor Layout in a Layout

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a working app and a layout that takes care of the sidemenu for all templates.

Is it possible to add another layout on top of that, to add a top nav-bar without changing the existing components?

Using Meteor 1.3 with Iron-Router

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: I'd say it's a fairly general question - is it possible to add a layout inside another layout in meteor?

Comment: Yes, but with out more context no one can give you a very good answer. Layouts are just other templates. and templates in meteor are composable, thus you can nest them. If you are using iron router or flow router, they both have different way of handling layouts. Or, if you are using react, that is again a different way of doing layouts.

Comment: I've edited the question to specify I'm using Iron-Router